# How do I externally reference rows from one sheet to another based on a non-numerical condition in one column no the original sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, cross-reference, conditional-statements

I currently have a large list of product information on a sheet in an Excel workbook. I want to copy and paste certain rows of data - the whole row - to a new sheet based on a certain column (all the "yes"'s need to be copied) and ignore the rows that do not meet the condition ("no"'s). How do I go about doing this without generating a bunch of blank rows?

On a side note, for down the line: I will have to rearrange all the data I externally reference from the first sheet into a whole new format (essentially swap the columns around in a different order based on how a certain company likes their data) Is there any way to automate that process based on column heading?

Comment: Filter the data on the "yes" column for "yes".  Then copy and paste.

Comment: Sorry- I should have mentioned more information. I cannot do that because the sheet I am pulling from is a master and is connected to 7 other sheets in a similar manner but based on different variables-so if I do that it messed with the other connected sheets. The end product of this is going to be an active, constantly updating sheet so a quick copy and paste wont work. I'm hoping there is a way to get excel to scan the column, identify all the yes's and insert them into the new sheet without any blank rows in between and have it all be an active constant equation. Thank you though

Comment: The only way to do that is to use Array formulas.  Depending on your dataset size this probably is not the best route, As it will kill Excel's calc times and may even kill excel itself.  You may want to look into Advanced Filter.  It has the ability to filter and copy to another page without messing up the data on the original page.

Comment: Please add any additional information to the original question using the `edit` function